# Map objects without overwriting existing one in React

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I have this code which every time, when button is clicked should filter product by entered value by user. This part works fine, but every time I try to add another product, it overwrites already mapped value. But I need to keep all entered products in the setLoadedProducts state.

```
  const [loadedProducts, setLoadedProducts] = useState([]);
  const [expeditionProducts, setExpeditionProducts] = useState([]);

  const addProduct = () => {
    const enteredProductEan = enteredEanRef.current.value;
    const filteredExpeditionProducts = expeditionProducts.filter(
      (order_item) => {
        return order_item.ean.toString() === enteredProductEan;
      }
    );

      const loadedExpeditionProducts = filteredExpeditionProducts.map(
        (invoiceData) => {
          return invoiceData;
        }
      );
      setLoadedProducts(loadedExpeditionProducts);
      setExpeditionProducts(
        expeditionProducts.filter(function (item) {
          return !filteredExpeditionProducts.includes(item);
        })
      );
```

Comment: Can you post your entire component code so we can help you better?

Comment: You're filtering `expeditionProducts` then using the filtered data to update your state. That's why your values are being overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for telling me the reason, I will know in future now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep adding more products to `loadedProducts` without losing  what you've already saved, you can include the value of your existing `loadedProducts` when you update state:

```
const newLoadedExpeditionProducts = filteredExpeditionProducts.map(
  (invoiceData) => {
    return invoiceData;
  }
);

setLoadedProducts(loadedProducts => [...loadedProducts, ...newLoadedExpeditionProducts]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something with ... but i couldn't make it on my own